# jquery loading twice on wordpress breaking down slider animation

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am having trouble with my staging site loading jquery twice when the site is loaded which as a result breaks the slider animation.

part of the source code including the lines where jquery is loading:

```
   '<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.yankrupnik.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.yankrupnik.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.yankrupnik.com/wp-content/themes/blocked/core/js/head.min.js?ver=1.1.6'></script>'
```

How can I load the jquery once to prevent conflicts ?

Thanks,

Comment: Where is it loading twice? Nothing you have shown is loading jquery twice.

Comment: it looks like twice from the wp-includes ( ver 1.11.1 and ver 1.2.1) folder and once from the wp-content ( ver 1.1.6) folder thanks

Comment: head.min.js ,jquery-migrate.min.js and jquery.js are being loaded. These all apear to be very different files.

Comment: jquery migrate is plugin to make old jquery version compatible. https://jquery.com/download/  Head is another plugin http://headjs.com/. You can remove jquery from loading by default, and load it manually. You should try that.

Comment: interesting I thought those files were conflicting each other and breaking down the slide functionality which not doesn't seem to be the case. any thoughts what might be causing the slider to break down?

Comment: @RicardoNuñez how can I remove it from loading by default ?

Comment: @jj00 I just added an answer explaining how you can do it. I had a similar issue debugging a theme from somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code below to the functions.php file. Start by deregistering jquery first, see if the problem still happening, then load it back with the second and third line of code.

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"), false, '2.1.3');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

Note: be aware that if your theme was using the migrate plugin, it's probably using old code, so you need to check if you need it or not and if everything is working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply  I have tried adding the first line to wp_deregister_script('jquery') and i got the following error :

http://pastebin.com/wj6eqWPL

Comment: Awesome the code works however the slider is still not animating any other suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: I checked the page source and its looks like the jquery-migrate.min.js script is no longer loading. The new jquery script that is loading now is : jquery.min.js?ver=2.1.3 can I use wp_register_script to load migrate plugin as well?

Comment: yes im getting two errors on the console :

TypeError: e.Tween is undefined

TypeError: window.Core is undefined

Comment: Try it, just remember to change the name. You can get it here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help and suggestion I will keep digging